# Showing div after scrolling doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, show

I want to show 'go to top' div after scrolling 150px but i really don't know how...I've tried a lot of scripts and nothing works.
This is my HTML:

```
<div id="goto_top" onClick="gotoId('top')" title="Иди на врх"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
   var h = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (h > 150) {
       $('#goto_top').fadeIn();
   } else {
       $('#goto_top').fadeOut();
   }
});
```

CSS:

```
#goto_top{
     position: fixed;
     background:url(../images/goto_top.png) transparent no-repeat;
     background-position: top center;
     padding:5px;
     width:35px;
     height:25px;
     bottom:40px;
     right:50px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

#goto_top:hover, #goto_top:active{
     background-position: bottom center;
}
```

**What is the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample here : [jsfiddle.net/6eF9g/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/6eF9g/1/)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 150) {
        $(".gotoTop").fadeIn();  
    } else {
        $(".gotoTop").fadeOut(); 
    }
});

$(".gotoTop").hide();

$(".gotoTop").click(function () {
    $("body,html").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Again...it's not working so i copied your code into new files but it's not working either in new files or in old ones. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: i created sample you can download https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhxv63ijn28cwhn/gotop.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing $(document) to $(window). Also, you should look into function debouncing, which is useful for situations like this, where you need to check some scroll position, but you don't want to necessary do it constantly and instantly, as it incurs a lot of overhead on the browser. You could debounce this function by 100ms and it would still seem fairly instantaneous to the user, while reducing a lot of browser overhead in the process.

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: I've just tried $(window) instead of $(document) and it's not working. Thanks for debouncing, i'll try that.